# Compiling Autotalent v2 Issues with Xcode 5.0.1 and Mavericks

Tags: xcode, audio, plugins, vst

I've been struggling to get [Auto Talent](http://www.olilarkin.co.uk/downloads/oldplugins/autotalent/) from Oli Larkin to compile for some time now. I'm pretty new to Xcode and that may be the issue, but either way I figured I'd see if anyone could help me. I'm trying to compile this in order to make a 64 bit version.

Starting from the top:

I've traced down a few things that I thought were the issues.

1. Noticed that wdl sdk was missing. Downloaded it from https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol. Added the wdl folder outside of the src folder.
2. Got some warnings when starting up Xcode 5.0.2. Let Xcode fix them.
3. Realized that the /Developer/Examples folder doesn't exist in Mavericks. Found https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012328-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2, downloaded the sample code, linked to AUBase as I realized this path needed updating in the AU Build Settings (see screenshot).
4. iPlug.xcodeproj is in red. Not sure what to do about this. Any ideas? I'm assuming it's important.

[image: Build Settings]
[image: Another shot of build settings]
[image]
[image]

**Update:** Based on the recent comments, I'm now getting somewhere. But, at the moment I'm getting the following errors. This has to do with not having a Lice SDK or something. Is this absolutely needed? If so, do you have the time to elaborate on this and where to get it? Thanks again for all of the help.

[image: Lice Errors]

It looks like I'm getting another issue as well related to clang. Maybe related to [Xcode - Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560239/xcode-command-developer-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1), not sure.

[image: clang errors]

**Note:** Before finally getting to the errors above, I had to...

1. Link CoreMIDI.framework "Frameworks and Libraries" -> "Linked Frameworks" -> App to /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework.
2. Set compiler in the build settings to default compiler. Otherwise it said unsupported compiler and threw some warnings. Hopefully this didn't mess anything up.
3. Rename aeffect.h and aeffectx.h to aeffect.h and aeffectx.h from the VST3 SDK. You can find these files in public.sdk -> source -> vst2.x. Apparently 2.x isn't really supported anymore. After renaming them, I moved them to the VST_SDK folder in WDL as the readme instructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the source you have will not compile straight off with recent versions of WDL-OL, since lots has changed. The way to upgrade it is to strip out the pertinent source code (i.e. autotalent.h/cpp and the mayer fft stuff) and re-duplicate one of the template projects in WDL-OL and bring it in to the new folder.

I've done it for you:

https://github.com/olilarkin/autotalent

you can clone this repository into the IPlugExamples folder of WDL-OL, and provided you've put all the SDK files in place it should compile straight off.

oli

Comment: I don't understand why I would clone your auto talent repo linked to above into one of the following folders. `IPlugChunks, IPlugControls, IPlugConvoEngine, IPlugDistortion, IPlugEEL, IPlugEffect, IPlugGUIResize, IPlugHostDetect, IPlugMonoSynth, IPlugMouseTest, IPlugMultiChannel, IPlugMultiTargets, IPlugOpenGL, IPlugPlush, IPlugPolySynth, IPlugResampler, IPlugSideChain, IPlugText` Note: These are the folders that I see within IPlugExamples. Can you elaborate on why I would do this? I'm basically just trying to use AutoTalent as a standalone plugin inside of 64bit Ableton.

Comment: i didn't say you should clone it inside one of those folders. It should be alongside those folders. Each of those folders is an iplug plugin, with relative paths to all the necessary source code       here is the path on my hd: /Users/oli/Dev/WDL-OL/IPlugExamples/autotalent

Comment: Realized that shortly after writing the comment. Thanks again. I've updated the main question a bit above with the latest issue.

Comment: i don't really have time to explain the all the issues i'm afraid. You can study the WDL forum to find out more about compiling with Xcode4 and Xcode5. You can't just rename the VST header files, they aeffect.h and aeffectx.h are different interface files. anyway i compiled the x64 version for you: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33721778/autotalent.zip

Comment: It sounds like I need to do some learning. Thanks for posting the 64 bit version and for your time.